# How to query SQLite to find sum, latest record, grouped by id, in between dates?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
Items (itemId, itemName)
Logs (logId, itemId, qtyAdded, qtyRemoved, availableStock, transactionDate)
```

Sample Data for Items:

```
itemId     itemName
  1         item 1
  2         item 2
```

Sample Data for Logs:

```
logid itemId qtyAdded qtyRemoved avlStock  transDateTime
  1      2     5405       0        5405     June 1 (4PM)
  2      2     1000       0        6405     June 2 (5PM)
  3      2        0    6000         405     June 3 (11PM)
```

I need to see all items from Items table and their SUM(qtyAdded), SUM(qtyRemoved), latest availableStock (there's an option for choosing the range of transactionDate but default gets all records). Order of date in final result does not matter.

Preferred result: (without date range)

```
itemName  qtyAddedSum  qtyRemovedSum avlStock
 item 1      6405          6000        405
 item 2           <nothing here yet>
```

With date Range between June 2 (8AM) and June 3 (11:01PM)

```
itemName qtyAddedSum qtyRemovedSum avlStock
 item 1      1000         6000       405
 item 2          <no transaction yet>
```

So as you can see, final result is grouped which makes almost all my previous query correct except my availableStock is always wrong. If I focus in the availableStock, I can't get the two sums.

Comment: Please, as a minimum of [mcve], provide the `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool, of a suitably tailored toy database.

Comment: The storage format for your date info is very important, if it does not fit usual formats you are largely out of luck and will need some unreadable `replace`magic to achieve anything.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm using Real for my date info here. Anyway, even if it is Text, it can be easily converted by datetime to be able to perform math operations.

Comment: Ok, I think I found something but I don't know if this is efficient     `SELECT * FROM Items LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Logs LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(qtyAdded) AS QtyAdded, SUM(qtyRemoved) AS QtyRemoved, availableStock AS Stock FROM Logs GROUP BY itemId) ORDER BY transactionDate DESC) USING (itemId) GROUP BY itemName;`

Answer (score 0):

you could use group by sum, and between

```
 select itemName, sum(qtyAdded), sum(qtyRemoved), sum(avlStock)
 from Items
 left join Logs on logs.itemId = items.itemId
 where transDateTime between '2017-06-02 08:00:00' and '2017-06-03 23:00:00'
 group by itemId
```

or

If you need  the last avlStock

```
   select itemName, sum(qtyAdded), sum(qtyRemoved), tt.avlStock
   from Items
   left join Logs on logs.itemId = items.itemId
   INNER JOIN (
     select logid,avlStock
    from logs
      inner join (
      select itemId, max(transDateTime) max_trans
      from Logs
      group by itemId
      )  t1 on logs.itemId = t1.ItemId and logs.transDateTime = t1.max_trans
   ) tt on tt.logId = Logs.itemId
   where transDateTime between '2017-06-02 08:00:00' and '2017-06-03 23:00:00'
   group by itemId
```

Comment: Nah, I don't need SUM(avlStock). I need the latest avlStock. My method of inputting it is to query first the db for the avlStock with transactionDate less than the current transactionDate, then add or subtract from it depending on my transaction if it is Add or Remove.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried both of these and they worked, can anyone confirm if these are already efficient or if there are some more efficient answers there.

```
SELECT * FROM Items LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM Logs LEFT JOIN
    (
          SELECT SUM(qtyAdd) AS QtyAdded, SUM(qtySub) AS QtyRemoved, availableStock AS Stock
          FROM Logs WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN julianday('2017-07-18 21:10:40')
          AND julianday('2017-07-18 21:12:00') GROUP BY itemId
    )
    ORDER BY transactionDate DESC
)
USING (itemId) GROUP BY itemName;


SELECT * FROM Items LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM Logs LEFT JOIN
    (
          SELECT SUM(qtyAdd) AS QtyAdded, SUM(qtySub) AS QtyRemoved, availableStock AS Stock
          FROM Logs GROUP BY itemId
    )
    ORDER BY transactionDate DESC
)
USING (itemId) GROUP BY itemName;
```